# How can empty all textboxes by click when 1 check box is checked in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

In my app I have a 85 textboxes. All textboxes in my app like this :

```
void textBox1s(string input)
{
    this.textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    this.textBox1.Text = input;
}

private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1s(Clipboard.GetText());
}
```

and now I want any textbox when checkbox is checked by Click/MouseClick on textbox1 >>>only empty textbox1.text
if click on textbox2 >>> only empty textbox2.text
and .....

and in my app i have tabControl1 and **18 groupbox**

how can set all textbox when checkbox is checked for empty by Click/MouseClick on textbox ?

**if my answer is use  user control  please give me 1 sample code**

Thanks.

Comment: A sample screenshot of your application will be helpful. Do you need to clear the textbox on a checkbox check/uncheck event or just the textbox click event

Comment: Just some advice if your application has 85 textboxes then you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Ramhound i think he's trying to build a GridView by it's self

Comment: Screenshot : http://up5.iranblog.com/images/fu1db62h42mi4sx6oh5s.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

neurotix was heading down the right track, but that won't catch your textboxes in child containers, nor will it handle calling the right function, to set the right textbox's properties. best way to handle it without an user control is to use a recursive function to assign your event handler.

```
public void SetTextBoxClickHandler(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
        if (childControl is TextBox)
        {
            childControl.Click += this.MyClickHandler;
            continue;
        }
        if (item.Controls == null)
            continue;
        SetTextBoxClickHandler(childControl);
    }
}

private void MyClickHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    typeof(Form).InvokeMember(string.Format("{0}s", ((Control)sender).Name), BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, new object[] { Clipboard.GetText() });
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetTextBoxClickHandler(this.Controls);
}
```

If you use an user control, that's really easy, just inherit from TextBox, and set everything to use the new control.

```
public class ClickableTextBox : TextBox
{
    public ClickableTextBox()
    {
        this.Click += MyClickHandler;
    }
    void setText(string input)
    {
        this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        this.Text = input;
    }

    private void MyClickHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        setText(Clipboard.GetText());
    }
}
```

I recommend creating the customer user control for the following reasons:

1. Avoid the performance hit of using reflection to invoke a method dynamically based on its name
2. Avoid the performance hit of converting the object sender to a Control on every click
3. Avoid the performance hit during the initialization loop of inspecting every control, and child control on the form, regardless if it's a TextBox or not
4. Less code to maintain
5. Higher reusability, the form code, would have to be present on every form, if you need to reuse this on a different project, or different form, it'd be a lot easier to reuse the custom user control rather than copying/pasting code to every form that might need to change

Of course, if all you need to do, is set the text, and nothing else in that function, you could simplify it a bit...

```
public void SetTextBoxClickHandler(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
        if (childControl is TextBox)
        {
            childControl.Click += this.MyClickHandler;
            continue;
        }
        if (item.Controls == null)
            continue;
        SetTextBoxClickHandler(childControl);
    }
}

private void MyClickHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as Textbox;
    if (textBox == null)
        return;
    textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    textBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetTextBoxClickHandler(this.Controls);
}
```

or using the user control:

```
public class ClickableTextBox : TextBox
{
    public ClickableTextBox()
    {
        this.Click += MyClickHandler;
    }

    private void MyClickHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        this.Text = input;
    }
}
```

For many of the above reasons, I'd still recommend the custom user control.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the Text this portion of code below will reset any text box which is clicked :

first declare the event Delegate

```
 private void AllTextBoxes_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(sender is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)(sender)).Text = "";
        }
```

than assign this to each Textbox, you can use VisualStudio Property Box to do that by selecting all Textboxes and assign that or do it manualy foreach one :

```
this.textBox2.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.AllTextBoxes_MouseClick);
```

or on FormLoad_Event you can do this

```
 foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    ctrl.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.AllTextBoxes_MouseClick);
                }
            }
```

and you can reset the TextBox text within a GroupBox like this

```
foreach (Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ctrl.Name);
                }
            }
```

for all GroupBoxes you can:

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)

    {
        if(control is GroupBox)
        {
        foreach (Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
                    {
                        if (ctrl is TextBox)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ctrl.Name);
                        }
                    }
        }
    {
```

Comment: good , but i think this code not work for any textbox in groupbox.  and At least 60 textbox in groupbox :(

Comment: @Mehrdad why do you think so ?

Comment: Wow Very Good Work :) and can u help me how can set it for all gropbox? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not exackly sure what do you mean but if you want to iterate through the collection of textbox you could do this like this:

```
    foreach (Control cntrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (cntrl is TextBox)
        {
            cntrl.Text = "lold";
        }
    }
```

where "this" is container like form

Answer (score 0):

From what I can ascertain, you want a checkbox to act as a toggle - when it's checked, delete the contents of a textbox, when it's unchecked, copy the clipboard into it.

The code for that would be:

```
void textBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    if (checkBox1.IsChecked)
    {
        tb.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        tb.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
    }
}
```

Then you can just make all of the Click() events on the textboxes point to this one method - hooray for code re-use :D

Comment: for all 85 textbox use this code ? 85 textbox .! i need 1 code for all text box this code not useful for me :-?

Comment: No, you can set all of the textboxes to use this one piece of code. Go to the form you're working on > click on a textbox, look at the properties window on the left-hand side, go to the events tab, find the MouseClick() event and replace the text in the field with textBox_MouseClick. Yes, you have to do this for all 85 textboxes but you only need to do it once. It's either that or pasting the above code into all of your current event handlers (of which I assume there is 85 too).

Comment: No. if click to any textbox clipboard only copy to tb.Text :)

Comment: Look at where 'tb' comes from - this is a standard EventHandler method. 'sender' is the object that raised the event - so if textBox1 calls it, it will be a reference to textBox1, and if textBox2 calls it, it will be a reference to textBox2 etc. So we can simply take sender and cast it into a TextBox (which I named 'tb') in order to get the text out of it.